# sql how to gete data faster? fetch count first and then fetch data or just fetch data directly

Tags: java, sql

I am tying to make my program run faster, that is my main goal. 
My program, written in java, fetch data from 3 tables.
Right now, for each table, it first uses this query to check if there are any data to fetch:

```
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FOLDER WHERE parentFolderID = ? " + 
"AND status NOT IN ('RM', 'TM')"
```

and then if there are use this query to get it:

```
SELECT folderid, foldertype, foldername, owner, description, "
        + "cabinetid, folderlevel, parentfolderid, status, lastmodified FROM folder WHERE parentFolderID = ? "
    + "AND status NOT IN ('RM', 'TM')
```

Is this the more efficient way or should I just fetch the data directly?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the execution plan of the query? What is the definition of the tables involved and what indexes did you create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the special case of your question I would avoid the `count` query. The `where`-clause is the same: that is if indexes are used or not: the physical "amount of work" to find the matching `rowids` (not to fetch the data found) is the same for both queries.

1. If no matching row is found both queries have almost the same performance overhead and no extra information is given.
2. If a matching row is found the second query is called anyway: the first query gives no additional information.

Probably a key for performance improvement might be the way how you get the value for `parentFolderID`: maybe you can join two different queries into one - depending on your database product.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `parentFolderID` and `status` are indexed, I would just fetch data directly without using count. The two query approach will be slower in my cases because it's two separate disk IO operations.

In empty result cases, both queries *should* have the same execution time since they'll just be reading off the index tree and won't be performing any subsequent random disk IO to fetch the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no black and white for this question. If your actual fetch would be a quite complex query, it may be better to look, if there are results, in the fist place.

If the second query is quite simple, fetching the count first might just be an additional (not required) query, as you can always retrieve the size of the final result.

Obviously it does not make sence to run the very same query, but only with count() instead of the values. (beside for lazy loading and pagination, where you need the count of all matching results)

However, if you join like 20 Tables with the `posts` table, and finally want every post that is newer than a date, you could check first, IF there is any post, that is newer than the given date.